# SyntaxError in Platform

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a SyntaxError in the Platform line but I cant see why.

Is it because the code should be wrapped in a class instead of a function?

```
function AccountItem({ title }) {
    account = title.join('\n')

    return (
        {Platform.OS === 'ios' ? (
            <TextInput 
                style={styles.title} 
                value={account} 
                multiline 
                editable={false} 
                scrollEnabled={false} 
            />
        ) : (
            <Text 
                selectable
                style={styles.title}
                >
                {account}
            </Text>
            )
        }
    )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think curly braces can only be used in the context of jsx. In other words, when they're inside some tags.

If you write curlies in a simple JavaScript context the parser expects an object literal, something like this:

```
({ propA, propB })
```

Rewriting it like below should make your example work:

```
return Platform.OS === 'ios' ? (
        <TextInput 
            style={styles.title} 
            value={account} 
            multiline 
            editable={false} 
            scrollEnabled={false} 
        />
    ) : (
        <Text 
            selectable
            style={styles.title}
            >
            {account}
        </Text>
    )
```